# Using objects when scanning a text file in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I'm trying to create a object in a main class from a different class, where the String input from main is supposed to be used in a method which counts how many times the specific word or String appears in a text file. But when I try to print out the counter, it just comes out as 0.

Here's the main class:

```
Ord forsteOrd = new Ord("Being");
forsteOrd.hentAntall();
```

Here's the class with the method I'm trying to reach:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Ord {

private String tekstord;
private int teller = 0;


public Ord(String tekst){
tekst = tekstord;}

public int hentAntall() throws Exception {
Scanner tekstfil = new Scanner(new File("scarlet.txt"));
while(tekstfil.hasNextLine()){
  String ord = tekstfil.nextLine();
  if(ord.equals(tekstord)){
    teller++;
  }
}
return teller;
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Comment: as `teller` is not defined inside the scope of `hentAntall` i´m feeling something is having a wrong scope.

Comment: Why don't you post your full classes?

Comment: Don't use `new File()`, just put the `String` directly into the `Scanner` constructor.

Comment: @Zircon you are wrong, in your case `Scanner` will use string as source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reason...

```
private String tekstord;   //by default it has "" in itself,i.e nothing;

public Ord(String tekst){
tekst = tekstord;}
```

So when your constructor runs,**tekst** is assigned the value which is stored in **tekstord**,i.e **""**.Now when your run **hentAntall**,

```
if(ord.equals(tekstord)){
    teller++;                     
  }
```

teller's value is never incremented,because **ord** has some String in it whereas **tekstord** has nothing because it has never been assigned anything,so they both are not equal and will never be equal and your teller's value is never incremented.

```
Solution..?
```

Instead of **tekst = tekstord**,interchange variables, **tekstord=tekst**.

Comment: Ahh didn't think it mattered which String you put first, but now I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The nextLine method returns all the file line. If the line contains exacltly the string "Being" the counter will be increased, otherwise not. 
E.g. a line like "Being " or "BeingBeing" will not increased the counter.

Comment: I used the word "Being" to check if the counter works, but it still comes out as zero even though I'm very certain the word appears several times throughout the .txt document.

Comment: what Daniele meant is that your code isn't counting how many times your word appears, it counts how many lines equals your word.

Comment: Isn't that pretty much the same thing?

Comment: Exacly Asoub, this because Knut use the String.equals method. @Knut: can you paste your scarlet.txt file?

Comment: Sure, it's very long though so I uploaded it here: http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1475760793518.txt